# Query subdocument in Meteor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a meteor project where I have the following collection:

```
problems = new Meteor.Collection("Problems")
```

A problem document is something like this:

```
problems.insert({Problem:{Message:m, Patient_name:p_name, Request:req}, DateStamp:datecntr});
```

Now I want to find all Problems where Request equals a given value. Therefore I have the following function:

```
Template.history_list.histories = function() {
 return problems.find({Problem:{$elemMatch:{Request:Session.get('history_label')}}});
};
```

In the template I have something like this

```
<template name="history_list">
 {{#each histories}}
 {{Problem.Message}}<br>
 {{/each}}
</template>
```

I have tried different constructions for my query, but nothing works. I have searched on mongodb.org and found the construction that you see here for querying subdocs, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Can someone helps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$elemMatch` is used for arrays, you don't have one. In your case, this should work:

```
Template.history_list.histories = function() {
  return problems.find({ 'Problem.Request': Session.get('history_label') });
};
```